# Android Clipboard - Pasting an image or selected webpage content to webpage or any other view/viewgroup

Tags: android, clipboard, copy-paste

I am trying to implement clipboard feature for my application. I am able to paste text but, It says 
"
In many cases an application can paste various types of streams of data. For example, an e-mail application may want to allow the user to paste an image or other binary data as an attachment. This is accomplished through the ContentResolver getStreamTypes(Uri, String) and openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(Uri, String, android.os.Bundle) methods. These allow a client to discover the type(s) of data that a particular content URI can make available as a stream and retrieve the stream of data.
"

What does it exactly means?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipData.html

above link describes that ClipData.Item can return three things 1) text 2) uri 2) intent. I am trying to copy an uri (http://www.google.com) and trying to run above example. While debugging, I can see the type and it says Text/plain. So, what exactly the URI is?

I am sorry, it is kind of two questions but both are related.

Thank you so much in advance